# read pdf page line by line given input as start and end page number - pdfbox java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf with 10 pages, I need to read page number 2 to 5 and end that whether the occurance of text `@@end` is there in pdf and then store it into the string then check for another `@@end`.

I have the following code:I am using pdfbox here

```
PDDocument pddDocument=PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf")); 
PDFTextStripper textStripper=new PDFTextStripper(); 
String text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument).toString();
```

It only allows me to read the entire pdf and store it into a `String text`. What I need is read the pdf from page number 2 to 5 and check the occurance of `@@end` , then do some operation, like the following

```
read the pdf from page number 2
.........
if(contains("@@end"))
do some operation
then check again till reaches page number 5
```

Please guide guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "secret" is

```
textStripper.setStartPage(p);
textStripper.setEndPage(p);
```

so you'll just do something like this (pages are zero based):

```
for (int p = 1; p <= 4; ++p)
{
    stripper.setStartPage(p);
    stripper.setEndPage(p);
    String text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
    if (text.contains("@@end"))
        // do stuff
}
```